# gets not working in TCP/IP chat program

Tags: c, sockets, tcp, send, gets

```
/* Server Code */
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
#include<string.h>
#include<unistd.h>
#include<sys/socket.h>
#include<sys/types.h>
#include<netinet/in.h>
#include<pthread.h>

#define MAXSIZE 50

void transmit();
void Recieve();

int sockfd, newsockfd, retval;
socklen_t actuallen;
int recedbytes, sentbytes;
struct sockaddr_in serveraddr, clientaddr;
//  char buff[MAXSIZE];
int a = 0, port_no;

main()
{   
  printf("Enter port number: ");
  scanf("%d",&port_no);

  sockfd=socket(AF_INET,SOCK_STREAM,0);
  if(sockfd==-1) {
    printf("\nSocket creation error");
    exit(-1);
  }

  serveraddr.sin_family=AF_INET;
  serveraddr.sin_port=htons(port_no);
  serveraddr.sin_addr.s_addr=htonl(INADDR_ANY);

  retval= bind(sockfd, (struct sockaddr*)&serveraddr, sizeof(serveraddr));
  if(retval == -1) {
    printf("Binding error");
    close(sockfd);
    exit(0);
  }

  retval = listen(sockfd, 1);
  if (retval == -1) {
    close(sockfd);
    exit(0);
  }

  actuallen = sizeof(clientaddr);
  newsockfd = accept(sockfd, (struct sockaddr*)&clientaddr, &actuallen);
  if(newsockfd == -1) {
    close(sockfd);
    exit(0);
  }

  int i=1; 
  pid_t pid = fork();
  if(pid == 0)
    transmit();
  else
    Recieve();

  close(newsockfd);
  close(sockfd);
}

void Recieve()
{
  char buff[50]; int f=1;
  while(f)
  { 
    recedbytes=recv(newsockfd,buff,sizeof(buff),0);
    if(recedbytes == -1) {
      close(sockfd);
      close(newsockfd);
      exit(0);
    }
    printf("recdbytes: %d\n", recedbytes);
    if(strcmp(buff, "Stop") == 0)
    {  
      puts("Closing");
      strcpy(buff,"Stop");

      sentbytes=send(newsockfd,buff,sizeof(buff),0);
      if(sentbytes == -1) {
        close(sockfd);
        close(newsockfd);
        exit(0);
      }
      f=0;
    }
    else {
      char cl[]="Client: ";
      strcat(cl,buff);
      puts(cl);
    }
  }
}

void transmit()
{
  char buff[50];
  while(1)
  {
    //  printf("%s","You: ");
    gets(buff);
    sentbytes = send(newsockfd, buff, sizeof(buff), 0);
    if(sentbytes == -1) {
      close(sockfd);
      close(newsockfd);
      exit(0);
    }
  }
}


/* Client Code */
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
#include<string.h>
#include<unistd.h>
#include<sys/socket.h>
#include<sys/types.h>
#include<netinet/in.h>
#include<pthread.h>

#define MAXSIZE 50 

void transmit();
void Recieve(); 

int sockfd, retval;
int recedbytes, sentbytes;
struct sockaddr_in serveraddr;
//  char buff[MAXSIZE];


main()
{        
  int port_no;
  printf("Enter port number:");
  scanf("%d",&port_no); 

  sockfd=socket(AF_INET,SOCK_STREAM,0);
  if(sockfd == -1) {
    printf("\nSocket creation error");
    exit(-1);
  }

  serveraddr.sin_family = AF_INET;
  serveraddr.sin_port = htons(port_no);
  serveraddr.sin_addr.s_addr = inet_addr("127.0.0.1");

  retval = connect(sockfd, (struct sockaddr*)&serveraddr, sizeof(serveraddr));
  if(retval == -1) {
    printf("Connection error"); close(sockfd);
    exit(0);
  }

  int i = 1;
  pid_t pid = fork();
  if(pid == 0)
    transmit();
  else
    Recieve();
  printf("\n");
  close(sockfd);
}

void Recieve()
{
  char buff[50];
  int f=1;
  while(f)
  {
    recedbytes = recv(sockfd, buff, sizeof(buff), 0);   
    if(recedbytes == -1) {
      close(sockfd);
      exit(0);
    }
    printf("recdbytes: %d\n",recedbytes);

    if(strcmp(buff, "Stop") == 0)
    {
      puts("Closing"); 
      f = 0;
      strcpy(buff, "Stop");
      sentbytes = send(sockfd, buff, sizeof(buff), 0);
      if(sentbytes == -1) {
        close(sockfd);
        exit(0);
      }
    }
    else {
      char sr[] = "Server :";
      strcat(sr, buff);
      puts(sr);
    }
  }
}

void transmit()
{
  char buff[50];
  while(1)
  { 
    //  printf("%s","You: ");
    gets(buff);
    sentbytes = send(sockfd, buff, sizeof(buff), 0);
    if(sentbytes == -1) {
      close(sockfd);
      exit(0);
    }
  }
}
```

I am trying to create a chat `server/client` program using `TCP/IP` and process creation in `C (linux)`.
It seems like the `gets(buff)` in `transmit` function of both the Client and Server Programs is not functioning as blocking and `send(..)` function is transmitting an empty buff. 
As a result, `"Client:"` or `"Server:"` in server program and client program respectively is being printed even if no data has actually been sent from the counterpart program.

Comment: don't use `gets`, use `fgets` function to read the line.

Comment: But isn't fgets for file input? I want to take input from the terminal(s).

Comment: You can mention `stdin` to get the input from standard in.

Comment: Yeah, I did that, it still doesn't seem to work.
I replaced gets with
 if(fgets(buff,sizeof(buff),stdin)!=NULL)
 {//send}'

Comment: `if(fgets(buff,sizeof(buff),stdin)!=NULL)
  {  //send buff
  }`

Comment: After receiving check the return value of `recv` and then make this line `buff[recvbytes]='\0';` After this `if(recvbytes== -1)` condition.

Comment: assign the `null` to all buffers you are using. `char buf[50]={0}`.

Comment: After adding  `buff[recedbytes]='\0'` : The program shows the number f recedbytes (I have printed it for debugging) and then simply terminates.

Comment: OT: It's `int main(void)` at least.

Comment: `recv()` might return less bytes then it was told to.

Answer (score 0):

```
recedbytes=recv(newsockfd,buff,sizeof(buff),0);
if(recedbytes == -1) {
  close(sockfd);
  close(newsockfd);
  exit(0);
}
printf("recdbytes: %d\n", recedbytes);
if(strcmp(buff, "Stop") == 0)
```

How are you expecting `strcmp` to know the length of the received string? You never did anything with `recedbytes`.

You also have numerous other bugs. You are expecting `recv` to somehow receive messages, despite the fact that you've never implemented any message protocol.

If you want to send and receive messages, you have to do three things:

1. Precisely define what a "message" is.
2. Write code to send a message.
3. Write code to receive a message.

There's no evidence in the code you've done any of these things. If your definition of a message is "precisely 50 bytes, always including a zero byte that marks the end of the data the receiver should process", then you may be okay on 1 and 2, but you definitely haven't done 3.